# The name 'isPost' does not exist in the current context (ASP.NET with Razor)

Tags: asp.net, razor, syntax-error

I'm trying to follow the [Microsoft Docs on getting started with Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c#a-simple-code-example). When I try to implement the following code I get the errors detailed in the comments:

`Solution/Project/Pages/AddNumbers.cshtml` :

```cs
@{
    var total = 0;
    var totalMessage = "";
    if(IsPost) { // The name 'isPost' does not exist in the current context

        // Retrieve the numbers that the user entered.
        var num1 = Request["text1"]; // CS0103  The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context
        var num2 = Request["text2"]; // CS0103  The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

        // Convert the entered strings into integers numbers and add.
        total = num1.AsInt() + num2.AsInt();
        totalMessage = "Total = " + total;
    }
}
```

I think I've followed the instructions faithfully, but can't think where I've made an error. What's the fix?

Answer (score 1):

`IsPost` does not exist if you do not create it. You can create such a property, defaulting to `false` and setting it to true in your `OnPost` handler.

Similarly, you cannot refer to `Request` like you tried in your code, you need a property for that too.

Since `num1` and `num2` were not successfully initialized, they cannot be successfully converted to `int` either.

Comment: Thanks Lajos. That makes sense to me. There is something that doesn't make sense to me though. The green tip box in this section of the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpmethods.ispost?view=aspnetcore-6.0 describes isPost as being a property available on "ASP.NET Web Pages". I can't find this on my Visual Studio and was using "ASP.NET Core Web App". I've a feeling it isn't available on here...

Comment: @JimmyTheCode it is a method of the `HttpMethods` class (see https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpMethods.IsPost(string)/). However, you do not even need this for the purpose of your Razor template. You can simply create a property, defaulting to false and setting it to true on your `OnPost` handler and use that property in your Razor. If my answer helped you solving your issue, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the documentation I was following is for "ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) 3", but I was trying to run the code on "ASP.NET Core Web App".

As Lajos Arpad pointed out, I would need to create my own `isPost` property .